# how to run actions/github-script in a specific directory

Tags: github-actions

We have a workflow which makes use of the `working-directory`. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun although this does not work with `uses`.

```
defaults:
 run:
  working-directory: applications/prod/kafka-ui
...
```

Below i use github-script.

```
    - name: Terraform Comment
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      env:
        TFPLAN_IDENTIFIER: "${{ steps.plan.outputs.tfplan_identifier}}"
        PLAN_OUTPUT: "${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}"
        PLAN_ERROR: "${{ steps.plan.outputs.stderr }}"
     with:
        script: |
```

How do i force github-script to run in a specific directory.

Comment: unfortunately that's not possible , as `uses` is referring to action and that action/workflow should have an explicit input defined within itself. This is known issue : https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25742

However you could fix it by creating a logic to change the directory inside your script and continue what you need.  `${{ github.workspace }}` is the root of the repo and then to wherever you want.